# AngularJS/HTML table formatting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

Having a bit of a nightmare with this - I'm trying to display a table of `$http` data using only `ng-repeat` and HTML.  I have this so far:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%" ng-repeat="data in boxData">
            <tr>
            <td>{{data.entity}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.securityID}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers[0].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers[1].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers[2].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.depot}}</td>
            <td>{{data.date}}</td>
            <td>{{data.date}}</td>
            <td>{{data.primeBroker}}</td>
            <td>{{data.activity}}</td>
            <td>{{data.timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{data.sequence}}</td>
            <td>{{data.activity}}</td>
            <td>{{data.balance[0].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.balance[1].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.balance[2].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.balance[3].value}}</td>
            <td>{{data.balance[4].value}}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

however it outputs this:

```
02  50167   42630125    US518252CR03    518252CR0   CCT 20160111        20160111    N   UPDATE  2016-02-03T20:01:39.015 4   UPDATE  -2352               
02  81106   7918922 IT0000062072    044998912   BNY 20160111    20160111    N   UPDATE  2016-02-03T20:01:42.158 4   UPDATE  532346              
01  51024   36530971    US404119BK49    404119BK4   CCT 20160118    20160118    N   UPDATE  2016-02-03T20:01:31.397 4   UPDATE  3886                
02  50555   39729417    US57183MCT53    57183MCT5   900 20160111    20160111    N   UPDATE  2016-02-03T20:01:39.661 20  UPDATE  66402000    -51402000
```

(I have deliberately not formatted this to give you as much of an idea as possible) If you can imagine the above but with a border around each cell, the border width defined by how long each number or string is *for each cell*.

I was expecting `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` to automatically create column widths possibly depending on the width of the widest cell in each column, but no column has an appropriate width, each cell is its own..

Comment: Can you please add a link of jsfiddle which can give a clear idea about the code.

Comment: @LinhPham got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `ng-repeat` in your `<tr>` tag.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in boxData">
        <td>{{data.entity}}</td>
        <td>{{data.security.securityID}}</td>
        <td>{{data.security.identifiers[0].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.security.identifiers[1].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.security.identifiers[2].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.depot}}</td>
        <td>{{data.date}}</td>
        <td>{{data.date}}</td>
        <td>{{data.primeBroker}}</td>
        <td>{{data.activity}}</td>
        <td>{{data.timestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{data.sequence}}</td>
        <td>{{data.activity}}</td>
        <td>{{data.balance[0].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.balance[1].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.balance[2].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.balance[3].value}}</td>
        <td>{{data.balance[4].value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go.

Comment: Brilliant, I'm thankful there are smarter people than me out there!  Will accept when the timer runs down :)